# In C, what exactly happens when you pass a NULL pointer to strcmp()?

Tags: c

I have read that the following results in undefined behavior.

```
strcmp(foo, NULL);
```

But what exactly happens "underneath the hood," so to speak? Is `foo` compared to garbage data? Is `NULL` dereferenced? What are the details that cause "undefined behavior"?

Comment: Who says the function has to fail?

Comment: Well, you can always look at the implementation source code...

Comment: The term "Undefined behavior" is intentionally vague because ANYTHING could happen. _ANYTHING_.

Comment: Undefined behavior means it is not spelled out what should happen. So the implementer could decide to whatever they feel best. The problem it creates is that one can't rely on reproducing the behavior one sees in one system or for that matter even on the same system if things change e.g. the runtime get updated or the program is compiled in a different way or the program is run in different conditions.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: It's not true that *anything* could happen; the behavior is still restricted by the rules of physics and logic. The point is that the C language standard imposes no requirements. If the call reformats your hard drive, you can complain to the vendor -- not because the C implementation violates the standard, but because it reformatted your hard drive.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Says "restricted to the rules of physics and logic". Writes C... :-)

Comment: Most likely thing that happened is that `NULL` is dereferenced. I'can't think of any other thing that would make the function fail

Comment: @KeithThompson: In your imaginary scenario, the vendor will then point you to the system's documentation where it says that reading from that memory location triggers a security erase of the hard drive and why this is a great feature.

Comment: @JoachimWagner: Maybe -- but the C standard doesn't require the vendor to document anything about what happens in that case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It depends on the implementation, which is free to assume your parameters are valid (i.e. not null in this case). The behaviour may or may not be reproducible from execution to execution, or from one implementation/platform to another.

Answer (score 28):

C11 makes this very clear in 7.1.4, "Use of library functions":

> Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed
>   descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as [...] a null pointer [...]) [...], the behavior is undefined.

The description of `strcmp` in 7.24.4 does not state otherwise, so the behaviour is indeed undefined.

Comment: Yes, as the OP acknowledged in the first sentence of the question.

Answer (score 5):

This is the current implementation of strcmp in glibc:

```
/* Compare S1 and S2, returning less than, equal to or
   greater than zero if S1 is lexicographically less than,
   equal to or greater than S2.  */
int
strcmp (p1, p2)
     const char *p1;
     const char *p2;
{
  const unsigned char *s1 = (const unsigned char *) p1;
  const unsigned char *s2 = (const unsigned char *) p2;
  unsigned char c1, c2;

  do
    {
      c1 = (unsigned char) *s1++;
      c2 = (unsigned char) *s2++;
      if (c1 == '\0')
    return c1 - c2;
    }
  while (c1 == c2);

  return c1 - c2;
}
```

Comment: Nope.  For example, many programmers of multiuser systems with memory protection might expect that dereferencing a null pointer will produce a bus error, but that's not necessarily the case on all platforms.  You could very well end up comparing foo to the interrupt vector table or the capacitive charge of undriven bus pins.

Comment: It actually does answer the question. In glibc, NULL does get dereferenced and an attempt to compare the "strings" is made, so depending on how the system responds to attempts to read memory addresses 0,1,2..., either the appropriate error is produced, or the string is compared to garbage data.

Comment: It does not answer the question, because you do not know that glibc is being used, and because you admit that even where glibc is used, what happens depends on how the host system responds to an attempt to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: Interesting detail in the code here exploiting the fact that modular arithmetic normally used for unsigned types is not used for c1-c2 because the result type is signed. To get that behaviour, one would have to write `return (unsigned char)(c1 - c2);`.

Answer (score 0):

You pass two pointers, and strcmp dereferences their contents and compares until it meets the difference or null character. Fail happens at different abstraction level, strcmp is fail-free on it's own. Many systems generate SIGSEGV signsl on dereferencing NULL pointer, but this is not the requirement.

Please note that ISO standards do not define many things, leaving implementation details up to implementations. At ISO C level there is nothing wrong with your example, but the results are not guaranteed to be predictable. (And no practical  test is guaranteed to be precise and reproducible, unless you consult the rules of underlying system and they say otherwise).

When we are talking about abstraction levels, we cannot ask "what if", because the rules are clear and say "do not do that, behavior is not defined here".